# Can iPhone app's send meeting requests

Tags: iphone

I have a client that wants an iPhone app that at some point sends a meeting request to a list of people.  Is this allowed?

Comment: You need to be more specific of what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific. It can if those people have the same app or it can send an e-mail to them. If you are unsure wether is allowed by apple I can tell you that it is.

Answer (score 0):

If event kit enables it seems like there should be no issues with this either.